# Passing / Accessing application’s services from npm packaged vue component library

Tags: vue.js

In my vue application, i have a service (axiosAuth.js) file implementing Axios interceptor which add authorization token to each request.

I created a component library which contains some shared components and api management class which will be packaged as npm package later.
These shared api call also need to be requested with same authorization token as the application. I am trying to pass the application's axiosAuth to plugin to be able to use same instance of the axios interceptor.

In the application, i am using the library as plugin,
`Vue.use(MyPlugin, { 'axiosAuth': mainAxiosAuth });`

In my library's install methods, i have access the options,

```
install (Vue, options) {
    if (!options || !options.axiosAuth) {
        throw new Error('Please initialise plugin with Axios instance.')
    }
    
    
     Vue.component('MyComponent1', "component1")
     Vue.component('MyComponent2', component2)

    ...
}
```

However, options are not available until "install" is executed and my .vue and .js files are loaded before that.

So, I created a wrapped class for axiosAuth in my library and replicated the axios interceptor as same as in the application.
But the authorization token is null on application load. Only once the user is login, the token information is updated and stored using vuex.
Passing the token on Vue.use as options gives "null" value in the library.

How can i have to access to axiosAuth of the application from the library plugin. Is there a way to use the Authorization token in the libray after the user is logged in?